# Hosting multiple sites with my apache2 configuration

Tags: apache-http-server

I want to host multiple different websites on my Apache2 server, however, I want the websites to be hosted inward toward my private IP range, non-accessible from the outside, and I want to host them like so:

```
localhost/drupal  #<= takes me to a drupal page
localhost/wordpress  #<= takes me to a wordpress page 
localhost/somerandompage  #<= takes me to another page
```

I know I can use the `VirtualHost *:80` like so:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

        ServerName drupal
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/drupal.com

        <Directory /var/www/drupal.com>
                Options +Indexes
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        DirectoryIndex index.html index.php

        LogLevel debug

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/drupal.com/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/drupal.com/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Is there a way I could host the websites like I want to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want the websites to be hosted inward toward my private IP range, non-accessible from the outside.

Setting aside firewall, configuration or other technical issues, any local computer that can contact your server on the network should have no problems accessing your web services normally.

To prevent "outside"    access, simply do not make your server publicly available (i.e. don't forward any ports to that server on your router).

> I want to host them like so:
>
> - localhost/drupal  #<= takes me to a drupal page
> - localhost/wordpress  #<= takes me to a wordpress page
> - localhost/somerandompage  #<= takes me to another page

Since you are apparently defining your DocumentRoot under `/var/www/html/drupal.com` in your VirtualHost block, simply add a e.g. `drupal` and `wordpress` folders in this directory and place the necessary files in each one (ex. Drupal in `/var/www/html/drupal.com/drupal` and WordPress in `/var/www/html/drupal.com/wordpress`).

For `somerandompage`, place the `.html`  file (or what have you) directly in the DocumentRoot i.e. `/var/www/html/drupal.com`.

Do note that `localhost` is a special name typically meant to refer to *127.0.0.1* (the host PC itself). If you want to have this as a name to refer to your web server from another local PC, you will likely need to modify the `hosts` file on each PC you wish to do this with (though as a suggestion, I would consider calling it something else to minimize confusion/issues).

Comment: So if I defined my document root under /var/www/html/hosts and defined my, lets say wordpress, website under /var/www/html/wordpress I should be able to go to http://host/wordpress and have access to it, vice versa with drupal?

Comment: Yes, with a couple notes. If you wanted to access http://host/wordpress and your document root was `/var/www/html/hosts`, the e.g. WordPress folder would have to be something like `/var/www/html/hosts/wordpress`. To have `/var/www/html/wordpress`, your DocumentRoot would need to be `/var/www/html/`. Second,  obviously, http://host/wordpress assumes *host* is a placeholder for an actual name for the server on the network. Third, the first Apache VirtualHost (default) overrides anything you have elsewhere (i.e. a `DocumentRoot` entry in your Apache  `.conf` file, say).

Comment: You're welcome. I hope you get everything set up satisfactorily. =)

Comment: Lol we'll see, we all know how linux can be! :P